# How to calculate the phase velocity of a partial standing wave

Tags: waves, velocity, phase-velocity

Partial Standing Waves

Partially Reflected Wave
A traveling wave encountering an impedance change will be partially reflected and transmitted. It can be represented as the sum of the incident (rightward) and reflected (leftward) waves as follows:

yr[x, t] =
$\text{Ai} \cos (t w-k x)$

yl[x, t] =
$\text{Ar} \cos (k x+t w)$

For a study region with a speed
c1 = 100
and a density
Rho1 = 1
the impedance is
Z1 = Rho1* c  = 100

It is bounded by a second region with speed
c2 = 500;
and density of
Rho2 = 1;
So that
Z2 = Rho2*c  = 500
The transmission and reflection coefficients are

Ar =
$\frac{\text{Z2}-\text{Z1}}{\text{Z1}+\text{Z2}}$

At =
$\frac{2 \text{Z2}}{\text{Z1}+\text{Z2}}$

This leads to
Ai = 1
Ar = 2/3 = .666
Set the parameters by choosing the region length to be 6 and the wavelength to be 6 so that the frequency f = c/lambda is as follows:
c=100;
f=100/6;
w=2 Pi f;
lambda=c/f;
k=2 Pi/lambda;
Set the length of the simulation to be a complete period, T = 1/f = 6/100
tLength=0.06;
With these parameters, the partial standing wave formed by the sum of the incident and reflected wave is shown below:

[image: A partial standing wave (forward and reverse)]

The plot shows a wave that looks like a standing wave that periodically "lurches" to the right. It is called partial standing wave.

It is interesting to examine how the wave appears to be stationary, and then moves to the right.
To see this more clearly, we will calculate the motion of the wave nodes, which are the zero points of the wave function.

The equation for the wave motion can be written as:

y[x, t] =
$\text{A1} \sin (k x) \sin (t w)+\text{A1} \cos (k x) \cos (t w)-\text{A2} \sin (k x) \sin (t w)+\text{A2} \cos
   (k x) \cos (t w)$

Solve for positions of Zeros
To find the motion of the wave nodes, solve for the zeroes of the wave function, y[x,t].
Make the substitution k = (w/c). Then,
y[x,t]=
$\text{A1} \sin (k x) \sin (t w)+\text{A1} \cos (k x) \cos (t w)-\text{A2} \sin (k x) \sin (t w)+\text{A2} \cos
   (k x) \cos (t w)$

Set this equation equal to zero, and solve for x. (I used Mathematica).

The solution for t = 0 can be written as
x[w, t] =
$2 \pi  \text{const}-\frac{c \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{(\text{A1}-\text{A2}) \tan (t
   w)}{\text{A1}+\text{A2}}\right)}{w}$

Choose the constant to be a positive integer, representing the first n resonant frequencies of the study area.
Next, define the function for the positions of the zeros as a function of time, angular frequency, and resonant frequency order.

The zero points as a function of time are:
xZero[t,w,j]=
$\frac{c \left(2 \pi  j-\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{(\text{A1}-\text{A2}) \tan (t
   w)}{\text{A1}+\text{A2}}\right)\right)}{w}$

To find Velocity and Acceleration of the Wave Nodes, differentiate with respect to t to get the velocity of the zeros

xZeroPrime[t, w]=

$\frac{c \left(\text{A1}^2-\text{A2}^2\right)}{\text{A1}^2+2 \text{A1} \text{A2} \cos (2 t
   w)+\text{A2}^2}$

Differentiate twice to get the acceleration of the zeros

xZeroPrimePrime[t, w]=
$\frac{4 \text{A1} \text{A2} c w \left(\text{A1}^2-\text{A2}^2\right) \sin (2 t w)}{\left(\text{A1}^2+2
   \text{A1} \text{A2} \cos (2 t w)+\text{A2}^2\right)^2}$

Plot the motion of wave nodes for different frequencies
[image: Partial standing wave an velocity of the nodes]
Plot Waveforms and Velocities of Nodes

y[x,t,w] =
$\frac{1}{3} \sin \left(\frac{100 \pi  t}{3}\right) \sin \left(\frac{\pi  x}{3}\right)+\frac{5}{3} \cos
   \left(\frac{100 \pi  t}{3}\right) \cos \left(\frac{\pi  x}{3}\right)$

Notice that the velocity of the nodal points ranges from 20 to 500.

Question: Is there another way to find Velocities of the Nodes

For some cases it is not possible to solve directly for the positions of the nodes.
For example, if the impedance profile varies or if the interface between differing impedances is a ramp or curve, the wave equation must be solved numerically.
It seems that there should be a way to find the speed of the nodes as they move.
I looked at phase or group velocity but cannot make that work even for the straightforward case above.
Can anyone help?